# Bizarre problem setting up IMAP mail in Thunderbird on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, thunderbird, evolution

Ubuntu 13.10.
 Thunderbird 24.2.0
 Exchange EWS Provider 3.2.0-Beta76 (the latest version of the add-in).

I use a hosted Exchange mail account (for several reasons - price and simplicity of synching between devices amongst others).
 Thunderbird will only connect to IMAP mail servers.
 This hosted Exchange mail has IMAP capability.
 If I set up the same version of Thunderbird on Windows 8, everything connects and works perfectly OK including Calendar, tasks and contacts.

If however I try setting this up in Ubuntu 13.10, using the same version of Thunderbird and the add-in, Thunderbird fails to connect to the IMAP server with the error message "Account cannot be verified - is the User name and Password correct?" - which of course they are.
 If I try setting up IMAP mail access in Evolution, the same error happens, so it's not just Thunderbird - it must be something in Ubuntu.
 Why should the Windows version connect OK and the Ubuntu version not?
 Anyone got any idea how I can fix this?
 (Other IMAP accounts such as GMail work perfectly OK......)

Comment: are you *really* sure you have the correct password? Maybe you have a different keyboard layout in Ubuntu and special characters get mixed up.

Comment: Nope - I am very sure it's all correct.